# How does Subtracting User Input Work in Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I know this is wrong pls help Search all over Yt and nothing on how to do it :( need to learn how to use maths with Variable

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_calc.*


class Calc : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc)


        var need = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.t_need)
        var money = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.t_money)
        var debt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.t_debt)

        var b_calc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.b_calc)


        b_calc.setOnClickListener {
            val diffrence = Money - debt         

            need.text = diffrence
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get text from a `textview` its usually a `Charsequence` therefore, you first need to `Parse` it to `int`. An example would be

```
var moneyText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.t_money)
var money = moneyText.toString().toInt()
```

From there, you can do this `money - debt` or with Kotlin you can do `money.minus(debt)` you can check out Kotlin arithmetic functions [here](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operators).